# Rolling multiple regression panel data

Tags: r, dplyr, regression

I am trying to perform a rolling regression for time t over the last 36 months for companies with observations for 18 of these months, but I am not able to make the function work. I only want the coefficient for var1. X, y, z are control variables.

Here is a sample of the data and the code I am trying to run.

```
structure(list(Year = c(2018, 2014, 2008, 2004, 2005, 2002, 2010, 
2008, 2013, 1998), Month = c(6, 12, 4, 6, 4, 8, 12, 11, 3, 3), 
    ISIN = c("NO0004895103", "NO0010571680", "NO0010010473", 
    "NO0003079709", "NO0003117202", "NO0003073801", "NO0010379266", 
    "NO0004913609", "NO0003072407", "NO0003679102"), SIZE = c(3637822300, 
    1.155e+10, 1925631048.5, 519688494.5, 790931587.08, 127597142.4, 
    2892152759.3, 554108244.7, 73484767, 375946560), BM = c(7.47698486077218e-07, 
    7.92202995594714e-07, 1.9900582030005e-07, 3.59385930497676e-07, 
    6.54209144403066e-07, 6.72227955087816e-07, 1.43273711611857e-06, 
    5.15824596832591e-07, 1.23252873661613e-06, 2.79726876987137e-07
    ), OP = c(0.145781283498513, 0.0433749257278669, 0.130477272126991, 
    0.211294037715838, 0.127523990874984, -0.0185266025249259, 
    -0.0822835066759631, 0.128844560922287, -0.0155446815227611, 
    0.416024745410667), INVEST = c(1.58608106515088, 0.00307252384303782, 
    0.33925195328069, -0.0984424241606425, 0.333479950150282, 
    0.13302885162465, -0.035773912311751, 0.408569401011161, 
    -0.206778240645154, -0.177187857233583), MonthlyReturn = c(-0.019509251810137, 
    0.095308641975309, 0.14864864864865, -0.034364261168385, 
    -0.064512147964095, -0.14080459770115, 0.13580244980708, 
    -0.1890214797136, -0.045226130653266, 0.39682527166336), 
    RiskFreeRate = c(0.00064, 0.00117, 0.00532, 0.00163, 0.00166, 
    0.00594, 0.00206, 0.00499, 0.00153, 0.00332), ShareTurnover = c(31649L, 
    907793L, 5318465L, 1831390L, 8956640L, 302000L, 7333090L, 
    516000L, 75553L, 2836550L), MarketExcessReturn = c(1.0813, 
    2.7638, 11.5701, 6.4672, -3.3108, -1.8598, 10.5445, -9.0969, 
    -0.0793, 10.8305), ExcessReturn = c(-2.0149251810137, 9.4138641975309, 
    14.332864864865, -3.5994261168385, -6.6172147964095, -14.674459770115, 
    13.374244980708, -19.40114797136, -4.6756130653266, 39.350527166336
    ), TradeDate = structure(c(17711, 16434, 13999, 12599, 12902, 
    11929, 14973, 14211, 15791, 10316), class = "Date"), GR_SIZE = structure(c(2L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", 
    "3"), class = "factor"), GR_OP = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    GR_BM = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), GR_INVEST = structure(c(3L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", 
    "3"), class = "factor"), SIZE_BM = structure(c(5L, 8L, 4L, 
    4L, 5L, 2L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("11", "12", "13", 
    "21", "22", "23", "31", "32", "33"), class = "factor"), SIZE_OP = structure(c(5L, 
    7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("11", "12", 
    "13", "21", "22", "23", "31", "32", "33"), class = "factor"), 
    SIZE_INVEST = structure(c(6L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("11", "12", "13", "21", "22", "23", "31", 
    "32", "33"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(17683, 
    16405, 13970, 12570, 12874, 11900, 14944, 14184, 15765, 10286
    ), class = "Date"), EPU_Paper = c(197.436482473082, 181.040599101032, 
    58.1799902251583, 62.5412044042803, 57.4799138334861, 52.420100605017, 
    61.1549363311955, 92.1818760618723, 76.2564063202547, 118.390708950295
    )), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
#merge dataframes
df_Final <- merge(df_Final, EPU_Paper, by = c("Year", "Month"))

# Create empty dataframe
date <- seq(as.Date("1991-01-31"),as.Date("2019-12-30"), by = "month")

Beta <- data.frame(ISIN = character(), Beta = numeric(), date =
                          as.Date(character()), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## Model
Returns_length <- 36 # No. of observations in rolling regression 
Returns_req <- 18 # observations of stocks requred in period 


for (i in 1:(length(date)-Returns_length)) {
  beta.tab <- df_Final %>% filter(TradeDate >= date[i] & TradeDate < date[i+Returns_length]) %>%
    group_by(ISIN) %>% filter(n() >= Returns_req) %>%
    do(ols.model = lm(data = df_Final, formula = ExcessReturn ~ var1 + x + y + z)) %>%
    mutate(Beta = coef(ols.model)[2]) %>% select("ISIN", "Beta") %>%
    mutate(TradeDate = date[Returns_length+i])
  Beta <- rbind(Beta, beta.tab)}
```

Comment: Hi j_t. You need to include some sort of sample of your data in order to help us help you. You can copy-paste the output from `dput(df_Final))` into your question.  If you think this is too much data to copy-paste, you could do `dput(sample_n(df_Final, size = 100))`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry! I have added a sample of the dataset now

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be multiple undefined inputs, `df_Final` and `EU_paper`, in the question but assuming that the data is in time order within group and that we want to apply `lm` to w rows from the current row to the row w-1 prior then using some generated data in the Note at the end we define a `coef.x` function to calculate the desired coefficient and a rolling function `roll` which uses it (here with width 2) and then apply it by group `g`.

```
library(zoo)

w <- 2
nr <- nrow(DF)
coef.x <- function(ix) coef(lm(y ~ x + x1, DF, subset = ix))[["x"]]
roll <- function(ix) rollapplyr(ix, w, coef.x, fill = NA)
transform(DF, coef.x = ave(1:nr, g, FUN = roll))
```

giving:

```
  y              x            x1 g        coef.x
1 1 -0.56047564655  0.4609162060 1            NA
2 2 -0.23017748948 -1.2650612346 1  3.0275676040
3 3  1.55870831415 -0.6868528519 1  0.5590071753
4 4  0.07050839142 -0.4456619701 2            NA
5 5  0.12928773516  1.2240817974 2 17.0127792594
6 6  1.71506498688  0.3598138271 2  0.6306055904
```

This could also be written using dplyr where `w`, `roll` and `coef.x` are from above:

```
library(dplyr, exclude = c("filter", "lag"))
library(zoo)

DF %>%
  group_by(g) %>%
  mutate(coef.x = roll(cur_group_rows())) %>%
  ungroup
```

### Note

```
# test data
set.seed(123)
DF <- data.frame(y = 1:6, x = rnorm(6), x1 = rnorm(6), 
  g = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2))
```

Comment: I have formulated a new, more detailed, post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64221542/rolling-multiple-regressions-with-panel-data  Somehow, I am not able to run your suggestion at all

Comment: Start a fresh instance of R, copy and paste the input in the Note  at the end and then copy and paste the code in the body of the answer.  You can see that it works because the answers shows the output from R that get when we do that.